# Mount & Blade Warband - Question Regarding Feasts

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I've encountered a strange issue with the process of holding feasts. As a vassal, you can hold up to as many feasts as you want and there is absolutely no limit or a cool-down timer between each one of them. When you're an independent ruler, on the other hand, your wife forces you to wait at least six days before organizing a new feast.

Question is, is there any way to bypass this little issue? I'd like to be able to hold as many feasts as I want without having the cool-down timer, just like it's completely possible as a vassal of any kingdom.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get some divorce papers?

Comment: How would it help? I can't host feasts without a wife by my side.

Comment: the thing is, holding feasts as a ruler so often is quite detrimental to your cause.  Your lords won't be back at their lands to defend against raiders, thus causing their relationship to decrease between them and your marshall (if you have appointed one).

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason why it was made this way. As a vassal you can hold as many feasts as you want because other vassals do not intend to come in such a big number (as compared to when Marshals or Lords hold feasts). If you were able to hold a feast as a Lord every time you would like to you would have been overrun in a matter of days. If you were at war your villages/towns will be deteriorating in quality because they would be raided by raiders or have their routes attacked.

You can bypass this issue by changing a value in one of the files.